# Remap Alt+Tab function to F3

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

Does anyone know how I can remap <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to the <kbd>F3</kbd> key?

So pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> will be the same as pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Download and install it then create a new AutoHotkey script by right-clicking e.g. the desktop then `New` > `AutoHotkey Script`. Right-click the new script then `Edit Script`. Copy and paste into it:

```
F3::Send, ^!{tab}
```

Save then run it. The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu should then appear when you press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

More info on how to use AutoHotkey can be found at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s11

Comment: Nice, thank you! What's the script so it executes the multitask to previous app, instead of showing the Alt+Tab menu? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just remove the `^`. It will then switch to the previous app instead.

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it

Comment: It's `F4::Send, Hello world`. If your string may contain special characters, use `SendRaw`. e.g. `F4::SendRaw, #Hello {world}` will paste `#Hello {world}` exactly as it is.

Comment: ahhh I manage to find the solution and deleted but you saw it hahah, thanks! Works perfectly now, just curious - is there a way to speed this up to make it instant? Currently it's "typing" character by character

Comment: You can put `SendMode Input` at the top of the script to make it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin privileges, download and use the new Microsoft utility called **PowerToys**. It allows key remapping using its **Keyboard Manager**.

Article describing how: https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/
Download from GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/
You will also need .Net installed: [enter link description here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1/runtime/)